# How to grab the last bit of a url before the "?" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this to grab the last part of the url:

```
url = window.location.href;                             
parts = url.split("/");

if (parts[parts.length-1].length == 0) {
    lastBit = parts[parts.length-2];
} else {
    lastBit = parts[parts.length-1];  
}
```

The above works with or without a forward slash. So if my url was:

```
http://mysite.com/path/to/welcome/
```

I would get just this:

```
welcome
```

But what if my url is:

```
http://mysite.com/path/to/welcome/?foo=bar&hello=bye
```

How can I still get "welcome" and disregard everything that comes after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a split on `?` before.

```
url = window.location.href;                             
urlParts = url.split('?');
parts = urlParts[0].split("/");

if (parts[parts.length-1].length == 0) {
    lastBit = parts[parts.length-2];
} else {
    lastBit = parts[parts.length-1];  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

<s>How about</s>

```
var urlWithoutSearch = location.href.replace(location.search, '');
```

Just use [`location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties):

```
var parts = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/$/, '').split('/'),
    lastBit = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

The `replace()` gets rid of a trailing `/` character, if present. (We don't care about a leading `/` in this case.)

Ex.

```
> '/path/to/welcome/'.replace(/\/$/, '').split('/')
> ["", "path", "to", "welcome"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [window.location.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) and work with this.  This variable just includes the path and does not include any query parameters.  So in your example you would be left with `/path/to/welcome` and parsing that is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

```
lastBit = window.location.pathname.match(/\/([^\/]+?)\/(?:\?|$)/i)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the query-string by:

```
url = window.location.href.replace(window.location.search, "");
```